# Cannot edit orders after change to https - OpenCart 2X

Tags: .htaccess, https, opencart

After changing into https and adding the following code to the .htaccess file:

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domainname\.com [NC]
 RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domainname.com/$1 [R,L]
```

I get a 'SytaxError:Unexpected end of JASON input error' when I want to edit an order.

When I revert to:

```
 #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domainname\.com [NC]
 #RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
 #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domainname.com/$1 [R,L]
```

the error goes away and I can edit. But in this case, the website is not secure anymore and an unsafe sign appears at the top left side of the browser next to the address section.

I want to keep the site at https and still edit the orders. Can anyone help?
Thank you...!

Comment: I suspect that you may've not changed config files. Replace all URL's in both `config.php` & `admin/config.php` to `https`. remove all instances of `http`. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: this is a bug that cropped up in different ways depending on version.  Which version of Opencart are you using?

Comment: OpenCart 2.0.1.1

Comment: @Rohit Butra Well done!! You have to edit the HTTP(S)_CATALOG also. But you have to do it after all the other procedures relating to implementing SSL or you can't get into admin panel. Thank you again!!